# Cannot create NEW Outbound Changeset when in Classic Experience

Tags: change-set, salesforce-classic, winter19

I get the following error whenever I try to create a new Outbound Change set in Sandbox:

> **Unable to Access Page**
>   The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

[image: Error msg]

Funnily enough it does create the new change set. However if you try to enter the newly created Change Set. The same error above will pop up again.

Please advise how I can solve this error as I prefer to configure using Classic rather than the slow LEX.

Comment: As the error suggests, you may need to reach out to customer support in this situation.

Comment: when does this error come? I mean while adding components, or uploading or during click of new changeset option?

Comment: When Clicking 'New' and going inside the changeset. Going inside the changeset I cannot get the view of adding components, upload or delete